# VueJS right way to edit prop without changing parent data

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

In my parent vue component I have a `user` object.

If I pass that user object to a child component as a prop:

```
<child :user="user"></child>
```

and in my child component I update `user.name`, it will get updated in the parent as well.

I want to edit the user object in child component without the changes being reflected in the user object that is in parent component.

Is there a better way to achieve this than cloning the object with: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't have to use the `JSON` object.

```
const child = {
  props:["user"],
  data(){
    return {
      localUser: Object.assign({}, this.user)
    }
  }
}
```

Use `localUser` (or whatever you want to call it) inside your child.

**Edit**

I had modified a fiddle created for another answer to this question to demonstrate the above concept and @user3743266 asked

> I'm coming to grips with this myself, and I'm finding this very
>   useful. Your example works well. In the child, you've created an
>   element in data that takes a copy of the prop, and the child works
>   with the copy. Interesting and useful, but... it's not clear to me
>   when the local copy gets updated if something else modifies the
>   parent. I modified your fiddle, removing the v-ifs so everything is
>   visible, and duplicating the edit component. If you modify name in one
>   component, the other is orphaned and gets no changes?

The current component looks like this:

```
Vue.component('edit-user', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="localUser.name">
    <button @click="$emit('save', localUser)">Save</button>
    <button @click="$emit('cancel')">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['user'],
  data() {
    return {
      localUser: Object.assign({}, this.user)
    }
  }
})
```

Because I made the design decision to use a local *copy* of the user, @user3743266 is correct, the component is not automatically updated. The *property* `user` is updated, but `localUser` is not. In this case, *if* you wanted to automatically update local data whenever the property changed, you would need a watcher.

```
Vue.component('edit-user', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="localUser.name">
    <button @click="$emit('save', localUser)">Save</button>
    <button @click="$emit('cancel')">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['user'],
  data() {
    return {
      localUser: Object.assign({}, this.user)
    }
  },
  watch:{
    user(newUser){
        this.localUser = Object.assign({}, newUser)
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32xoy9Lw/13/).

This allows you full control over when/if the local data is updated or emitted. For example, you might want to check a condition before updating the local state.

```
  watch:{
    user(newUser){
      if (condition)
        this.localUser = Object.assign({}, newUser)
    }
  }
```

As I said elsewhere, there are times when you might want to take advantage of objects properties being mutable, but there are also times like this where you might want more control.

Comment: @user3743266 Added some explanation.

Comment: Very nice. That has been very interesting thank you. Vue rocks my grandma. I think Evan You is in reality a team of 30 rocket scientists.

Comment: Are you sure? I would say this thread, and your answer, have tons of value. Questions like this are potentially relevant to everyone who uses vue. Leave it, and it could have a long and surprising life.

Comment: `Object.assign` doesn't deep-copy the entire object (just the first layer it seems). So a nested property like `object.key1.key2` will change in both parent and child. A way around it is to use `localUser: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.user))`

Answer (score 1):

in the above solutions, the watcher won't trigger at first binding, only at prop change. To solve this,  use immediate=true

```
watch: {
  test: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal, oldVal)
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components), children "can't" and "shouldn't" modify the data of their parents. But [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/32xoy9Lw/7/) you can see that if a parent passes some reactive data as a property to a child, it's pass-by-reference and the parent sees the child's changes. This is probably what you want most of the time, no? You're only modifying the data the parent has explicitly shared. If you want the child to have an independent copy of `user`, you could maybe do this with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) but beware you'll be serializing Vue-injected properties. When would you do it? Remember props are reactive, so the parent could send down a new user at any time, wiping out local changes?

Perhaps you need to tell us more about why you want the child to have it's own copy? What is the child going to do with its copy? If the child's user is derived from the parent user in some systematic way (uppercasing all text or something), have a look at computed properties.

Comment: It's not what you want most of the time, no. If the property value changes, the local data will *not* be wiped out (unless you specifically set it up to do so).There are any number of reasons why you do not want changes in the child *immediately* reflected in the parent. Consider the case of someone wanting to cancel their changes. If you make changes to the data passed in the property, you have to come up with some additional solution for backing out all those changes. If you make a copy first and only make changes to the parent when you $emit the data, then you can cancel at any time.

Comment: You say data will not be wiped, but this is exactly what happens in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/32xoy9Lw/7/) if you pass reactive data to a child as a property. Parent and child are sharing one source of truth? How would you implement your undo scenario?

Comment: I said *data*, as in data properties, not the property itself. I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32xoy9Lw/10/). Notice that now, you can easily cancel out of changes made in the child because the child only emits changes when you intend to. If you edited the user property directly and you wanted to cancel, you would have to do something like save the original state, and restore it. I agree with you that it is *convenient* you can mutate object and array properties, but also less *maintainable*. You should be careful about when you mutate a property. It shouldn't be your default.

Comment: I'm coming to grips with this myself, and I'm finding this very useful. Your example works well. In the child, you've created an element in `data` that takes a copy of the prop, and the child works with the copy. Interesting and useful, *but*... it's not clear to me when the local copy gets updated if something *else* modifies the parent. [I modified your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/32xoy9Lw/11/), removing the v-ifs so everything is visible, and duplicating the edit component. If you modify `name` in one component, the other is orphaned and gets no changes?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a data variable just with the information you want to be locally editable and load the value in the created method

```
data() {
return { localUserData: {name: '', (...)}
}
(...)
created() {
    this.localUserData.name = this.user.name;
}
```

This way you keep it clear of which data you are editing. Depending on the need, you may want to have a watcher to update the localData in case the user prop changes.