# Vue.js component prop without 2 way binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I found [this question that is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790842/vuejs-right-way-to-edit-prop-without-changing-parent-data), but it did not explain the issue I am trying to solve for. (Using Vue.js 2)

I have an array of objects (users), that I display as a list.
I want to open an "edit user" modal component, which needs to prefill the form values with the user data (exact parent object), but I do not want to edit the parent data until I click a save button that verifies the data before emitting an input event with the new values of the object.

I do not want to manually call out each property to create a new "clean" object (if I change the data type this is a headache), but Vue is adding its reactivity to the user object and therefore modifying the value in the component updates the parent value at the same time.

I also want to wait for the server to confirm a change is saved before emitting the input event; therefore the parent won't update until the data is confirmed on the server.

Is there a recommended pattern for non-reactively modifying props in components, instead using the emitted `input` event to update, as per the [Vue component prop/event specs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)?

Note: I already have a working example, save for the concern with separating the reactivity bit.

Comment: Make a local copy of the parent data in the child component. Edit the copy, and when you are ready, update the parent by emitting the new version.

Comment: I actually have an answer in question you linked that details how to do this that I deleted. I've undeleted it and you can take a look if it addresses your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791310/38065

Comment: Definitely a good answer (gave it an upvote so you can be comfortable sticking it up). I'm still not super happy about this seemingly complex workaround for what I would assume is a common design pattern, but I guess that's the tradeoff with built-in reactivity all the time?

Comment: This is moreso a javascript issue. There isn't a lot that Vue can do to protect you from modifying properties of an object. It can keep you from changing the object *reference* (setting the prop to a completely new object). If, for example, you passed the individual properties as props (assuming the properties are primitive values) then you would not be able to change the values.

Comment: My point is that even Vue tries to create this one-way pattern for its users, as based on this part of the docs:(https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events). It fails to provide a pattern for dealing with objects that were made reactive by Vue. I guess you're right though that it's an issue with JS's pass by reference for all objects. I come from a Backbone background, where you just pass a model to whatever view you need, and you have to build the reactivity/UI-binding manually.

Comment: I don't disagree. It's something you realize as you work with it. In my early work I thought it was awesome and just took advantage of it. Now that I've run across more use cases, I take care to be aware of the differences.