# Vue.js passing item in items to component as prop: will I be modifying prop?

Tags: vue.js

New to Vue.js. From the docs, one simple example is to use components to render each item in a list, like this:

```
<todo-item
      v-for="item in groceryList"
      v-bind:todo="item"
      v-bind:key="item.id">
    </todo-item>

Vue.component('todo-item', {
  // The todo-item component now accepts a
  // "prop", which is like a custom attribute.
  // This prop is called todo.
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<li>{{ todo.text }}</li>'
})

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    groceryList: [
      { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables' },
      { id: 1, text: 'Cheese' },
      { id: 2, text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat' }
    ]
  }
})
```

(Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Composing-with-Components)

My question is: what is the correct way of changing, for example, a todo text? Please note: **I DO** want to change the parent data, and the possible duplicates are cases where people DO NOT want to change the parent data.

My initial idea was to use `<input v-model="todo.text">` in the component template. And it works. I find this nice because it updates the array of to-dos in the root component `data` attribute, which means I don't have to write an event to make the changed data bubble up.

But there's a problem. Reading on the docs in components, I saw this:

All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, **but not the other way around**. **This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state**, which can make your app’s data flow harder to reason about.
In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. **This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.**

If I understood this correctly, I should NOT try to change the todo text the way I did, because even tough it works, I'm changing a prop inside a child component (since each todo is passed to a child component via a prop).

But the documentation clearly says that Vue would warn me against this practice in the console, but I see no warnings.

Also, if this is not a best practice, how should I make a change in the to-do name correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS right way to edit prop without changing parent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790842/vuejs-right-way-to-edit-prop-without-changing-parent-data)

Comment: See also discussion here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004871

Comment: Keep reading [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events). You send an event to the parent to tell it to update the variable.

Comment: @RoyJ I know I could use custom events, but that adds a lot of extra complexity and `<input v-model="todo.text">` is working perfectly. Also, if it's not the right way to do it, why Vue is not printing any errors in the console as the documentation says it would ?

Answer (score 2):

Vue will not notice if you modify the members of a prop. It will only notice (and warn) if you try to modify the prop itself.

"It works" is not the same as "best practice". The best practice is for only the owner of a data item to modify it. That requires a certain amount of additional coding for emitting and handling events. You may decide it's not worth the extra effort, and most of the time that will not bite you, particularly in simple applications. In a complex application, you may find that unit testing works a lot better with fully-encapsulated components.

The snippet below is one way to handle it without a *custom* event: catch the *native* `change` event (you could catch the native `input` event if you preferred).

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  // The todo-item component now accepts a
  // "prop", which is like a custom attribute.
  // This prop is called todo.
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<input :value="todo.text">'
})

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    groceryList: [{
        id: 0,
        text: 'Vegetables'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Cheese'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    setText(item, event) {
      item.text = event;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app-7">
  <todo-item v-for="item in groceryList" :todo="item" :key="item.id" @change.native="setText(item, $event.target.value)">
  </todo-item>
  <div v-for="item in groceryList">
    {{item.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```