# What does todo.text refer to?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to learn vue.js and have came across this line of code.

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  props: ['todo'],
  template: '<li>{{ todo.text }}</li>'
})

var app7 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-7',
  data: {
    groceryList: [
      { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables' },
      { id: 1, text: 'Cheese' },
      { id: 2, text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat' }
    ]
  }
})
```

I could not figure out what does todo.text here refer to, since I do not see a todo object with text as one of its objects. Sorry for the noob question! Thanks!

Comment: Your component has a prop called `todo`. Whoever includes the component has to pass in an object, and that object should have a `text` field in it.

Comment: See an example of that over at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46126365/14955 It loops over all items in `groceryList` and each of those becomes a `todo`.

Comment: @Thilo, thank you for the tip, I'll go check it out!

Comment: When asking questions please provide full code available, or where you "came across this code" also just for future.

Comment: @MichaelMano no problem. I'll take note about this as well. Thanks for the help.