# Editing a form with save and cancel options

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, forms, vue-component

I'm new to VueJS. I'm trying to create a form with simple Save and Cancel functionality. When binding the model to form fields they get updated immediately as the inputs are changed, but I don't want that tight binding. Instead, I want to be able to save and submit when the "Save" button is pressed and revert the changes when the "Cancel" button is pressed.

What's the suggested Vue way of doing this?

It would also be ideal if we can show the server save status and indicate it on the form if the submission is failed. If you know of any examples or samples that would be hugely helpful. Thanks!

See in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orad/k5j6zj9t/)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      First Name:
      <input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" :disabled="!isEditing"
             :class="{view: !isEditing}">
    </div><div>
      Last Name:
      <input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" :disabled="!isEditing"
             :class="{view: !isEditing}">  
    </div>
    <button @click="isEditing = !isEditing">
      {{ isEditing ? 'Save' : 'Edit' }}
    </button>
    <button v-if="isEditing" @click="isEditing = false">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      isEditing: false,
      user: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
      }
    }
  })
</script>

<style>
  .view {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: initial;
    color: initial
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Generally, make a component out of the form, emit the changes when you want to. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791310/38065).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS right way to edit prop without changing parent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790842/vuejs-right-way-to-edit-prop-without-changing-parent-data)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.  That question is specifically about props from a parent component where this is about a single component and the usage of `v-model`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a few ways to handle this.  You could create a separate component for the form, pass props to it, and then handle the editing/saving by emitting changes or if you want to keep it in a single component you could use `value` binding and `refs`, e.g.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isEditing: false,
    user: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Smith'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      this.user.firstName = this.$refs['first_name'].value;
      this.user.lastName = this.$refs['last_name'].value;
      this.isEditing = !this.isEditing;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.view {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: initial;
  color: initial
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ref="first_name" :value="user.firstName" :disabled="!isEditing"
           :class="{view: !isEditing}">
  </div><div>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" ref="last_name" :value="user.lastName" :disabled="!isEditing"
           :class="{view: !isEditing}">  
  </div>
  <button @click="isEditing = !isEditing" v-if="!isEditing">
    Edit
  </button>
  <button @click="save" v-else-if="isEditing">
  Save
  </button>
  
  <button v-if="isEditing" @click="isEditing = false">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Or you could use a variable cache mechanism (with suggested edits) e.g.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isEditing: false,
    user: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Smith',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.cachedUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      this.cachedUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);
      this.isEditing = false;
    },
    cancel() {
      this.user = Object.assign({}, this.cachedUser);
      this.isEditing = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.view {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: initial;
  color: initial
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" :disabled="!isEditing"
           :class="{view: !isEditing}">
  </div><div>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" :disabled="!isEditing"
           :class="{view: !isEditing}">  
  </div>
  <button @click="isEditing = !isEditing" v-if="!isEditing">Edit</button>
  <button @click="save" v-else-if="isEditing">Save</button>
  <button v-if="isEditing" @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

With any of these options you can set a status message at the start of the `save` method and then update it whenever you're done with the server call.

Comment: Great! With a little improvement, I think I have a good [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/k5j6zj9t/1/) now. Feel free to add it to your answer if you want.

Comment: @orad Yeah that does look better, just wanted to get the point across.  I added it to the solution though!

Comment: What if the source of the data is a prop?  I am getting an error indicating that I should "Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders" and suggesting use of computed properties instead, but if I use computed properties, the code just gets more complicated to bind with custom getter/setters.  :/

Comment: @JonathanB. Yeah computed properties won't work well for this because it's one by one and doesn't allow you to save or cancel all at once.  Checkout [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/akqm2jzb/)  I wrote up.  It's essentially using the props as "cached variables" and emitting an object to the parent when the `save` method is hit or resetting the local vars to the props if `cancel` is hit.