# Editing fields with Vue & Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a page where I want a user to be able to edit their room information. For example the name of the room. The code I have currently is that it shows the `roomName` in an `h3` and if they click on the `edit` button, then the property `edit` is changed to true (this will then show the `text-field` instead of the `h3`).

```
<!-- Room Name -->
<h2 v-if="edit == false">{{ roomName }}</h2>
  <!-- EDIT -->
  <v-text-field
      v-else
      label="Room Name"
      v-model="roomName"
   />

<!--Edit Button-->
<v-btn v-if="edit == false" 
       @click="edit = true" 
       class="filter">Edit</v-btn>

<!--Cancel Button-->
<v-btn v-if="edit == true" 
       @click="cancelEdit" 
       class="filter">Cancel</v-btn>
```

**The problem is**: That if a user presses cancel I don't want it to update the property `roomName`. I try to do this by rerunning a computed property that grabs the `roomName` from the store. However I doesn't allow me to call a computed property in `cancelEdit`.

The reason I'm using a `roomName` property & `v-model`, and not directly using the value from the computed property is... because I don't understand how I can grab the value from an input if I press `save`.

How can I grab the value from an input or how can I make a cancel button with this structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing a form with save and cancel options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166359/editing-a-form-with-save-and-cancel-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet to see if it can help you,

I didn't use `vuex` but you can your initial values from your store:

https://jsbin.com/yefiqinewu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Perfect thanks mate, after messing around with this a bit, it ended up working for my set up, much appreciated.