# Vue.js edit post by id

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm starting with vue.js and I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166359/editing-a-form-with-save-and-cancel-options) to help me loading some posts from DB with `v-for`.

Below each post there are `Edit` and `Delete` buttons. I can delete each post by its ID correctly. And I can open the `input` to edit post title correctly too.

But I cannot save `input` changes when I click on save button. It returns to the initial text.

And when I click to edit it opens all the `inputs` titles.

Is there a way to open the specific post title and keep the changes after save it?

```
<div id="app" class="row mb-50">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in tours" v-bind:key="item.id" id="tours" class="col-md-12 mb-30">
        <div class="tour-list">
            <div class="tour-list-title">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" ref="item.id" :value="item.title" :disabled="!editingTour"
                        :class="{view: !editingTour}" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="tour-list-description">
                <p>
                    {{ item.description }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="tour-list-options">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <span>
                            <button @click="editingTour = !editingTour" v-if="!editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Edit</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button @click="save" v-if="editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-edit-btn">Save</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button @click="editingTour = false" v-if="editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Cancel</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button @click="deleteTour(item.id, index)" v-if="!editingTour"
                                class="btn border btn-circle tour-list-delete-btn">Delete</buton>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

vue.js:

```
let app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    editingTour: false,
        tours: null,
        errored: false,
        edited: false,
        deleted: false,
        item: {
            title: null,
            description: null
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.searchTour()
    },
    methods: {
        searchTour: function () {
            axios.post('getPosts.php', { "token": param }).then((response) => {
                this.tours = response.data;
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errored = error;
            });
        },
        editTour: function (id) {
            axios.post('editPosts.php', { "token": token, "tourID": id }).then((response) => {
                this.edited = response.data;
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errored = error;
            });
        },
        deleteTour: function (id) {
            if (confirm('Are You sure?')) {
                const index = this.tours.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
                if (~index) {
                    axios.post('deletePosts.php', { "token": token, "tourID": id }).then((response) => {
                        this.deleted = response;
                        this.tours.splice(index, 1);
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        this.errored = error;
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        save: function () {
            this.item.title = this.$refs['item.id'].value;
            this.editingTour = !this.editingTour;
            console.log(this.item.title);
        }
    }
});
```

In `console.log(this.item.title);` is returning `undefined`.

I have changed `ref="item.id"` to `ref="title"` and `this.item.title = this.$refs['item.id'].value;` to `this.item.title = this.$refs['title'].value;` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements. It automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type. Although a bit magical, v-model is essentially syntax sugar for updating data on user input events, plus special care for some edge cases.

Source : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Example:

```
<input v-model="description" placeholder="my description">
```

The above input value will then be binded to the description element of your data object and vice-versa - if one changes, the other is updated to the same value:

```
data:{
description: "default value"
}
```

So, when you DB request is ready you can update the value of the description within the DB method:

```
this.description=db.result.description
```

and the value of the input will also update.

Likewise, if the user changes the value of the input field, the value bound to the data element will be updated also. So, when saving back to DB:

```
db.update({description:this.description})
```

(note: the db methods here are for example purposes only. Replace with the relevant DB methods for your backend service.)

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out

Comment: did you get there in the end?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I got it. First part is working. It's keeping the changes and I can update post title in DB. But second part of my problem (*And when I click to edit it opens all the inputs titles.*) still remains.

Comment: it might make it easier if you move the item content into it's own component. So, everything in the foreach goes into new component which would have it's own business logic for a single record.

Answer (score 1):

You should use in your input `v-model` instead of `ref` it will bind your model with the value you are editing, in general in vue we avoid direct DOM manipulation when possible, like so:

```
<input type="text" ref="item.id" v-model="item.title" :disabled="!editingTour"
                        :class="{view: !editingTour}" />
```

Where calling your function e.g. editTour you can pass it the `item` (if it's in the template to save the updated version like so:

```
@click="editTour(item)"
```

Comment: Great! It's working. Is it possible to open an input at a time? When I click to edit the first title all the other inputs also open.